# Filling the data frame with duplicates based on another with unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

I have a dataframe with unique IDs:

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
df_Unique <- matrix(rnorm(20),4,5)
colnames(df_Unique) <- paste0("k_",1:5)
rownames(df_Unique) <- paste0("Project",1:4)

                k_1        k_2        k_3         k_4         k_5
Project1 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026
Project2  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621
Project3 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120
Project4  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132
```

And I have another dataframe with the duplicates of the Project names:

```
df_Dublicates <- matrix(NA,12,5)
colnames(df_Dublicates) <- paste0("k_",1:5)
rownames(df_Dublicates) <- sample(paste0("Project",1:4),size = 12,replace = T)

         k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4 k_5
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Project2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I want the values in `df_Unique` to be replicated accordingly for the `df_Dublicates` data frame. I am not sure which function to use for this case.

Comment: There is a slight twist compared to the duplicated question, but the answer is exactly the same: `df_Unique[rownames(df_Dublicates), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. Just subset with the "duplicated" rownames:

```
df_Unique[rownames(df_Dublicates),]
```

PS: You don't show data.frames in your question. Those are matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My real dataset also contains characters.